# How to use 'as ... as' and 'so ... as' in comparison.

Tags: comparison

I have read some articles about the subject on this web pages but I am not sure.

Did I understand it correct?

> **not as** adjective **as** - when we compare the same things (the same kinds)

E.g.:

1. This apple is not as nice as that apple.
2. This apple is not as nice as that apple.
3. I'm not as tall as Anna.
4. My mother is not as old as my father.

> **not so** adjective **as** - when we compare different things (different kinds)

E.g.:

1. This apple is not so nice as that orange.
2. I'm not so tall as the horse.
3. My grandmother is not so old as the wardrobe.
4. My head is not so big as the melon.
5. I'm not so intelligent as a dolphin.

> **as** adjective **as** - when we compare the same things (the same kinds)

E.g.:

1. This apple is as nice as that apple.
2. This apple is as nice as that apple.
3. I am as tall as Anna.
4. My mother is as old as my father.

> **so** adjective **as** - when we compare different things (different kinds)

E.g.:

1. This apple is so nice as that orange.
2. I am so tall as the horse.
3. My grandmother is so old as the wardrobe.
4. My head is so big as the melon.
5. I am so intelligent as a dolphin.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*So ... as* occurs only in negative contexts:

> I am not <sup>OK</sup>so tall as Anna, *but not*
>   I am <sup>∗</sup>so tall as Anna.

Two generations ago, the most formal registers preferred *so* in negative contexts, but that 'rule' has largely disappeared now. Today you may use *as ... as* in any register and any context. The only exceptions are a couple of uses of *so much* with nouns and verbs:

> She never so much as looked at him.
>   She didn't give him so much as a look.
>   She didn't so much insult him as ignore him.

*As ... as* is not prohibited but is fairly rare in these constructions.

Comment: What does the three following sentences mean? 

"She never so much as looked at him.
She didn't give him so much as a look.
She didn't so much insult him as ignore him."

Any link which explains this structure?

Comment: Just asked on ELU. Any references?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth CGEL, 14.4.3, p. 1130. "[...] *so* occurs only in non-affirmative contexts--most are negatives [...], but other types are found too, such as interrogative [...]. *As* can replace *so* in these contexts, where indeed it is more frequent. *So* is also used in some of the comparative idioms discussed in §4.5 below." These are the *so much as* and *so far as* idioms. "Two generations ago" is my own experience.

Comment: Thanks. Probably best submitted on ELU.